# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required. Dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, database, dataframe, dictionary, key-value

I try to connect to a database and write data into a table from csv file. I have a such code and when I launch this code I receive this error:

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

I have a such csv file

```
0;Antimatter price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2020;3
1;Antimatter price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2030;3.3
2;Antimatter price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2040;3.33
3;Antimatter price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2050;4.44
4;Fusion price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2020;1.7
5;Fusion price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2030;1.7
6;Fusion price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2040;1.7
7;Fusion price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2050;1.7
8;Naquadria price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2020;10.0
9;Naquadria price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2030;18.1
10;Naquadria price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2040;26.2
11;Naquadria price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2050;32.3
12;Power Cristals price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2020;5.5
13;Power Cristals price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2030;9.9
14;Power Cristals price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2040;11.11
15;Power Cristals price;Euro (2010) / GJ;2050;14.4
16;CO2 certificate price ;Euro (2010) / ton;2020;40
17;CO2 certificate price ;Euro (2010) / ton;2030;80
18;CO2 certificate price ;Euro (2010) / ton;2040;160
19;CO2 certificate price ;Euro (2010) / ton;2050;320
20;Gross domestic product;Billion Euro (2000);2020;1000
21;Gross domestic product;Billion Euro (2010);2030;2000
```

It’s my code with csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
import getpass
oem2orm.setup_logger()
os.environ["OEP_TOKEN"] = getpass.getpass('Token:')
db = oem2orm.setup_db_connection()
metadata_folder = oem2orm.select_oem_dir(oem_folder_name="/home/daryna/tutorial/upload/metadata")
tables_orm = oem2orm.collect_tables_from_oem(db, metadata_folder)
oem2orm.create_tables(db, tables_orm)
filepath = "./data/upload_tutorial_example_data.csv"
example_df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding='utf8', sep=';')
example_df[:10]
schema = "model_draft"
table_name = "upload_tutorial_example_data"
connection = db.engine
try: 
    example_df.to_sql(table_name, connection, schema=schema, if_exists='append', index=False)
    
    print('Inserted data to ' + schema + '.' + table_name)
except Exception as e:
command = text('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS upload_tutorial_example_data;')
 connection.execute(command.execution_options(autocommit=True))

    print('Writing to ' + table_name + ' failed!')
    print('Note that you cannot load the same data into the table twice. There will be an id conflict.')
    print('Delete and recreate with the commands above, if you want to test your upload again.')
```

I tried to create a dictionary manually as long as it says in the error, but the error repeated itself when I started it. It’s my code with dictionary which I created:

```
from oem2orm import oep_oedialect_oem2orm as oem2orm
import os
import pandas as pd
import getpass
oem2orm.setup_logger()
os.environ["OEP_TOKEN"] = getpass.getpass('Enter your token')
db = oem2orm.setup_db_connection()
metadata_folder = oem2orm.select_oem_dir(oem_folder_name="/home/daryna/tutorial/upload/metadata")
tables_orm = oem2orm.collect_tables_from_oem(db, metadata_folder)
oem2orm.create_tables(db, tables_orm)
filepath = "/home/daryna/tutorial/upload/data/upload_tutorial_example_data.csv"
example_dict = {'id': ['1', '2'], 'variable': ['rrr', 'sss']}
example_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dict)
schema = "model_draft"
table_name = "upload_tutorial_example_data"
connection = db.engine
try:
   example_df.to_sql(table_name, connection, schema=schema, if_exists='append', index=False, sep=',')
   print('Inserted data to ' + schema + '.' + table_name)
except Exception as e:
   command = text('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS upload_tutorial_example_data;')
   connection.execute(command.execution_options(autocommit=True))
   # session.rollback()
   print('Writing to ' + table_name + ' failed!')
   print('Note that you cannot load the same data into the table twice. There will be an id conflict.')
   print('Delete and recreate with the commands above, if you want to test your upload again.')
```

I got the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 23
     22 try:
---> 23     example_df.to_sql(table_name, connection, schema=schema, if_exists='append', index=False)
     24     print('Inserted data to ' + schema + '.' + table_name)

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:2987, in NDFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2985 from pandas.io import sql
-> 2987 return sql.to_sql(
   2988     self,
   2989     name,
   2990     con,
   2991     schema=schema,
   2992     if_exists=if_exists,
   2993     index=index,
   2994     index_label=index_label,
   2995     chunksize=chunksize,
   2996     dtype=dtype,
   2997     method=method,
   2998 )

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:695, in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
    691     raise NotImplementedError(
    692         "'frame' argument should be either a Series or a DataFrame"
    693     )
--> 695 return pandas_sql.to_sql(
    696     frame,
    697     name,
    698     if_exists=if_exists,
    699     index=index,
    700     index_label=index_label,
    701     schema=schema,
    702     chunksize=chunksize,
    703     dtype=dtype,
    704     method=method,
    705     engine=engine,
    706     **engine_kwargs,
    707 )

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1726, in SQLDatabase.to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
   1678 """
   1679 Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
   1680 
   (...)
   1724     Any additional kwargs are passed to the engine.
   1725 """
-> 1726 sql_engine = get_engine(engine)
   1728 table = self.prep_table(
   1729     frame=frame,
   1730     name=name,
   (...)
   1735     dtype=dtype,
   1736 )

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1354, in get_engine(engine)
   1352             error_msgs += "\n - " + str(err)
-> 1354     raise ImportError(
   1355         "Unable to find a usable engine; "
   1356         "tried using: 'sqlalchemy'.\n"
   1357         "A suitable version of "
   1358         "sqlalchemy is required for sql I/O "
   1359         "support.\n"
   1360         "Trying to import the above resulted in these errors:"
   1361         f"{error_msgs}"
   1362     )
   1364 elif engine == "sqlalchemy":

ImportError: Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'sqlalchemy'.
A suitable version of sqlalchemy is required for sql I/O support.
Trying to import the above resulted in these errors:
 - Pandas requires version '1.4.16' or newer of 'sqlalchemy' (version '1.3.14' currently installed).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 27
     25 except Exception as e:
     26     command = text('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS upload_tutorial_example_data;')
---> 27     connection.execute(command.execution_options(autocommit=True))
     28     # session.rollback()
     29     print('Writing to ' + table_name + ' failed!')

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2191, in Engine.execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   2175 """Executes the given construct and returns a :class:`.ResultProxy`.
   2176 
   2177 The arguments are the same as those used by
   (...)
   2187 
   2188 """
   2190 connection = self._contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
-> 2191 return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:984, in Connection.execute(self, object_, *multiparams, **params)
    980     util.raise_(
    981         exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object_), replace_context=err
    982     )
    983 else:
--> 984     return meth(self, multiparams, params)

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:293, in ClauseElement._execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    291 def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
    292     if self.supports_execution:
--> 293         return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    294     else:
    295         raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1097, in Connection._execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1087 else:
   1088     compiled_sql = elem.compile(
   1089         dialect=dialect,
   1090         column_keys=keys,
   (...)
   1094         else None,
   1095     )
-> 1097 ret = self._execute_context(
   1098     dialect,
   1099     dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_compiled,
   1100     compiled_sql,
   1101     distilled_params,
   1102     compiled_sql,
   1103     distilled_params,
   1104 )
   1105 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:
   1106     self.dispatch.after_execute(self, elem, multiparams, params, ret)

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1287, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1284             result._autoclose_connection = True
   1286 except BaseException as e:
-> 1287     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
   1288         e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1289     )
   1291 return result

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1485, in Connection._handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1481         util.raise_(
   1482             sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   1483         )
   1484     else:
-> 1485         util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
   1487 finally:
   1488     del self._reentrant_error

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:178, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    175     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    177 try:
--> 178     raise exception
    179 finally:
    180     # credit to
    181     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    182     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    183     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1247, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1245                 break
   1246     if not evt_handled:
-> 1247         self.dialect.do_execute(
   1248             cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1249         )
   1251 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:
   1252     self.dispatch.after_cursor_execute(
   1253         self,
   1254         cursor,
   (...)
   1258         context.executemany,
   1259     )

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:588, in DefaultDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    587 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 588     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

File ~/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oedialect/engine.py:324, in OECursor.execute(self, query_obj, params)
    322 else:
    323     query = query_obj
--> 324 query = dict(query)
    325 requires_connection_id = query.get('requires_connection', False)
    327 query['connection_id'] = self.__connection._id 
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

If someone knows how to correct this error, help please

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The error says implies that you are running an old version of SQLAlchemy.

```
ImportError: Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'sqlalchemy'.
A suitable version of sqlalchemy is required for sql I/O support.
Trying to import the above resulted in these errors:
 - Pandas requires version '1.4.16' or newer of 'sqlalchemy' (version '1.3.14' currently installed).
```

Assuming you are working from a notebook:

```
!pip install --upgrade SQLAlchemy
```

From the terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: I upgraded SQLAlchemy and receive
``Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy
  Attempting uninstall: SQLAlchemy
    Found existing installation: SQLAlchemy 1.3.14
    Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-1.3.14:
      Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-1.3.14
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
oem2orm 0.3.2 requires sqlalchemy==1.3.14, but you have sqlalchemy 2.0.5.post1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed SQLAlchemy-2.0.5.post1
``

Comment: @Daryna I unfortunately cannot help you with that: you will have to change your approach. ```oem2orm 0.3.2``` requires ```sqlalchemy==1.3.14```; however, to use Pandas, you need ```sqlalchemy``` version ```'1.4.16'``` or newer, which is in conflict with ```oem2orm```  requirements!

Comment: Maybe you could try the following import:
```from sqlalchemy.sql import text```

If the error is only a dependency one, you could try also opening an issue on their GitHub:

https://github.com/OpenEnergyPlatform/oem2orm/issues